# How to store and read SQL queries from properties or yml file in spring boot jdbc repository?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc, properties-file

I am using spring boot and spring jdbc template. I want to externalize the SQL queries in either properties or yml file. I dont want to store the SQL queries in the java repositories classes.

What is the best way to handle this case?

This is how my repository class looks right now.

```
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImpl extends BaseRepository implements UserRepository {

    @Override
    public List<User> findAll(){
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM users";
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery,  userMapper);
    }

    @Override
    public User findById(Long userId){
        String sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :userId";
        Map<String, String> namedParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        namedParameters.put("userId", String.valueOf(userId));
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sqlQuery, namedParameters, userMapper);
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution for this?

Comment: @andre3wap Nope. Not yet

Comment: I want to do the same thing. have you found any good solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I handled as follows:

I have a `@Configuration` class which creates jdbcTemplate beans so I add an  another bean with class of `StringBuilder` to hold query from .sql file. Here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class DBManager {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DBManager.class);

    @Autowired
    PropertiesUtils propertiesUtils;

    @Bean(name = "targetJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate targetJdbcTemplate() throws SQLException {
        Environment environment = propertiesUtils.getEnvironment();
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("db.target.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("db.target.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("db.target.password"));

        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "targetQueryTemplate")
    public StringBuilder targetQueryTemplate() {
        return propertiesUtils.getSQLQueryFromFile(DBDirection.TARGET_DB);
    }
}
```

`PropertiesUtil` looks like:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:app.properties"})
public class PropertiesUtils {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PropertiesUtils.class);

    @Resource
    private Environment environment;

    public Environment getEnvironment() {
        return environment;
    }

    /**
     * to get sql query from .sql file
     * @param dbDirection which db's query is needed
     * @return a StringBuilder object which holds needed sql query
     */
    public StringBuilder getSQLQueryFromFile(DBDirection dbDirection) {
        String filePath = null;
        StringBuilder sql = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        InputStreamReader input = null;
        try {
            if (dbDirection == DBDirection.SOURCE_DB)
                filePath = this.environment.getProperty("db.source.query.file");
            else if (dbDirection == DBDirection.TARGET_DB){
                filePath = this.environment.getProperty("db.target.query.file");

            if(filePath == null || filePath.equals("")) {
                logger.error("filePath cannot be null or empty");
                return sql;
            }

            InputStream in = PropertiesUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath);
            input = new InputStreamReader(in);
            br = new BufferedReader(input);
            String str;
            sql = new StringBuilder("");
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sql.append(str);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Failed to read query from file", e);
        } finally {
            try {
                if(br != null)
                    br.close();
                if(input != null)
                    input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Failed to close reader", e);
            }
        }
        return sql;
    }
}
```

`app.properties` holds .sql file's path. getSQLQueryFromFile reads the file once while context initializing.

Then I wire the query holder bean (targetQueryTemplate) to my repo that's it. Here is my repo:

```
@Repository
public class TargetRepository implements ITargetRepository {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TargetRepository.class);
    private static final String DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("targetJdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate targetJdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("targetQueryTemplate")
    private StringBuilder targetQueryTemplate;

    @Override
    public void testConnection() {
        targetJdbcTemplate.execute("select 1 from dual");
    }

    @Override
    public int[] insert(final ArrayList<Object> list) {
        return targetJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(this.targetQueryTemplate.toString(), new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, int i) throws SQLException {
                // batch adding
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return determineBatchSize(list);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly address how your ask regarding properties files or yml, but I interpret your question generally as asking about the best way to manage sql statements in a project. Having worked on projects with quite a lot of SQL code I've found MyBatis to hold up without too much complaint. In a nutshell, it already handles externalizing sql to external xml files and can keep the manageability of the sql in the files at a good level as you accumulate more sql.

To set it up you basically need to configure the beans and create two mybatis xml files along with a java interface for the repository.  Taking your example, here's the mybatis for the user repository:

```
public class User {

  private Long id;
  private String name;

 ...
}

public interface UserRepository {

  List<User> findAll();

  User findById( @Param( "id" ) Long userId );

}
```

The @Param will map the 'id' value to the #{id} expression in the SQL

META-INF/repo/sql/userMapper.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.bushcoder.so.app.user.UserRepository">

    <resultMap id="user" type="com.bushcoder.so.app.user.User">
        <id property="id" column="userId"/>
        <result property="name" column="name"/>
    </resultMap>

    <select id="findAll" resultMap="user">
        SELECT id, name FROM user
    </select>

    <select id="findById" parameterType="long" resultMap="user">
        SELECT id, name FROM user WHERE id = #{id}
    </select>

</mapper>
```

Note: #{id} will be supplied the value passed in via the call to userRepository.findById

META-INF/repo/sql/sqlmap-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//www.mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd" >
<configuration>

    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="META-INF/repo/sql/userMapper.xml"/>
    </mappers>

</configuration>
```

The 'META-INF/repo/sql/sqlmap-config.xml' path will be used in the Java Config to setup the beans required by mybatis. So for the configuration you'll need 4 beans: sqlSessionFactory, sqlSessionTemplate, dataSource and the userRepository.  These need to be somewhere in a configuration class for Spring to process.

```
  @Bean
  public SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
    SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
    sqlSessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sqlSessionFactory.setConfigLocation( new ClassPathResource( "META-INF/repo/sql/sqlmap-config.xml" ) );
    return sqlSessionFactory.getObject();
  }

  @Bean
  public SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new SqlSessionTemplate(sqlSessionFactory());
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
        .setType( EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
        .addScript("META-INF/repo/db/ddl/create-database-script.sql")
        .addScript("META-INF/repo/db/dml/database-seeder-script.sql")
        .build();
    return db;
  }

  @Bean
  public UserRepository userRepository() throws Exception {
    return sqlSessionTemplate().getMapper( UserRepository.class );
  }
```

In my prototype project I went to the H2 database and am using the EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder to take care of the schema and seed data.

META-INF/repo/db/ddl/create-database-script.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS user (
  id    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  name  VARCHAR(30)
);
```

META-INF/repo/db/dml/database-seeder-script.sql:

```
INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES (1, 'BOB');
INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES (2, 'LARRY');
INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES (3, 'FRANK');
INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES (4, 'CHARLIE');
INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES (5, 'GARRY');
```

More than likely you'll wire the repository into a service.  Might look something like this:

```
public interface UserService {

  List<User> findAll();

  User findById(Long userId);

}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

  @Inject
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Override
  public List<User> findAll() {
    return userRepository.findAll();
  }

  @Override
  public User findById( Long userId ) {
    return userRepository.findById( userId );
  }
}
```

The calling code could be like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import ( AppConfig.class )
public class MybatisConfigExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run( MybatisConfigExampleApplication.class, args );

        final UserService users = ( UserService ) context.getBean( "userServiceImpl" );

        final List<User> allUsers = users.findAll();
        System.out.println( "allUsers = " + allUsers );

        final User userById_5 = users.findById( 5L );
        System.out.println( "userById_5 = " + userById_5 );
    }
}
```

Now, as you start to accumulate more sql, you would create a new repository interface, its matching mapper file, link the mapper xml file via the sqlmap-config xml file by adding a new `<mapper>` element for it, and then add the new repository as a bean in Spring's config.  Moreover, and I didn't show it hear, if userMapper.xml starts to get too large and cumbersome you can break it apart into smaller files and still keep the UserRepository interface.

Comment: I have looked into it. It seems to be almost 2.6 yrs old. Since, a lot has changed in spring  since, is there any better way to do it now?